# nginx tomcat proxy return a incorrect url

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I have request a jsp like index.jsp.
there are some links in the jsp

```
<a href="/test/a.jsp">A</a>
<a href="/test/b.jsp">B</a>
```

but after clicking the A tag I get a incorrect url like "http://tomcat_server/test/a.jsp".

1. [tomcat_server] is the tomcat proxy name configurated in nginx.
2. [test] is the web project name deployed in tomcat.

following code is my nginx configuration.

nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;                          
worker_processes  auto;         
worker_cpu_affinity auto;

error_log  /opt/logs/nginx/nginx_error.log  error;      

pid        /dev/shm/nginx.pid;          

#Specifies the value for maximum file descriptors that can be opened by this process.
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

dso {
     load ngx_http_footer_filter_module.so;
     load ngx_http_limit_conn_module.so;
     load ngx_http_limit_req_module.so;
     load ngx_http_sysguard_module.so;
     load ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_module.so;
     load ngx_http_upstream_least_conn_module.so;
     load ngx_http_upstream_session_sticky_module.so;
}

events {
        use epoll;                                      
    worker_connections  51200;      
}


http {
    include       mime.types;                                       
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    charset  utf-8;    

    log_format  access  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" $http_x_forwarded_for';             

    open_log_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s min_uses=2 valid=1m;


    server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;    
    client_header_buffer_size 256k;      
    large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;  


    #size limits
    client_max_body_size          50m;      
    client_header_timeout         3m;       
    client_body_timeout           3m;      
    send_timeout                  3m;      
    sendfile                      on;      
    tcp_nopush                    on;      
    keepalive_timeout             60;      
    tcp_nodelay                   on;      
    server_tokens                 on;      

    server_name_in_redirect off;
    server_info off;        
    server_tag off;     

    limit_req_log_level error; 
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m; 
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:30m rate=10r/s;



    include  gzip.conf;                     
    include  proxy.conf;                    
    include  vhost/*.conf;                  
    include  mysvrhost.conf;               


}
```

proxy.conf

```
proxy_temp_path   /dev/shm/nginx/proxy_temp;

proxy_cache_path  /dev/shm/nginx/proxy_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache_one:500m inactive=1d max_size=30g;

client_body_buffer_size  512k;     
proxy_connect_timeout    50;       
proxy_read_timeout       600;      
proxy_send_timeout       600;      
proxy_buffer_size        128k;     
proxy_buffers           16 256k;   
proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;      
proxy_temp_file_write_size 1024m;  
#proxy_ignore_client_abort  on;    

proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503 http_404 http_502 http_504;
```

mysvrhost.conf

```
upstream tomcat_server {
 server 127.0.0.1:18080;
}
```

tomcat1.conf [under the vhost directory]

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        index index.html index.htm;

        root /opt/tomcat/webapps;

        access_log  /opt/logs/nginx/localhost.log  access buffer=24k;



        limit_req zone=one burst=50;
        limit_conn perip 50;

        if (-d $request_filename){
            #rewrite http://$host/aa.jsp permanent;
            rewrite ^/(.*)([^/])$ http://$host/$1$2/ permanent;
        }

        location ~ ^/(WEB-INF)/ {
                deny all;
        }

    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
              allow           all;
             allow            127.0.0.1;
             allow            192.168.0.0/16;
             #deny             all;
             proxy_cache_purge    cache_one   $host$1$is_args$args;
             error_page 405 =200 /purge$1;          
            }  
           if ( $request_method = "PURGE" ) {
             rewrite ^(.*)$ /purge$1 last;
            } 


        location ~ 404\.html$ {
            root /opt/tomcat/webapps;            
            proxy_set_header Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;
            add_header      X-Cache   Cache-Skip;
            expires 3d;
    }

        location ~ .*/(upload)/ {
            root         /opt/tomcat/webapps/upload;
                access_log   off;
        }


        location ~ .*\.(html)?$  {
        proxy_next_upstream http_502 http_504 error timeout invalid_header;
             proxy_cache cache_one;

             root /opt/tomcat/webapps;                           
            proxy_cache_valid  200 304 12h;

             proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
             add_header      X-Cache   Cache;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|rar|zip|css|js|woff|ttf|svg)$ {

            root /opt/tomcat/webapps;
            access_log   off;

             proxy_next_upstream http_502 http_504 error timeout invalid_header;
             proxy_cache cache_one;

             proxy_cache_valid  200 304 12h;

              proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
             add_header      X-Cache   Cache;
        }

         location ~ .*\.(htm|do|action|jsp)?$  {
             proxy_next_upstream http_502 http_504 error timeout invalid_header;
             proxy_cache cache_one;                  
             proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;
        }

         location /  {
            proxy_next_upstream http_502 http_504 error timeout invalid_header;
             proxy_cache cache_one;                  
             proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;
        }   

        location /NginxStatus {
            stub_status on;
            access_log off;
            auth_basic "NginxStatus";
        }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /404.html;


}
```

I am not familiar with nginx.I couldn't fixed position of the incorrect configuration .

Any help on this is greatly appreciated,thanks!

Comment: Its not clear what the problem is, show full nginx.conf file and the errors from logs.

Comment: @itpp13 I have completed the configuration of nginx.

Comment: Ok, where is the error log(s) and what is the problem? configuration wise you get exactly from what you have made.

Comment: @itpp13 I am sorry about replying message so late.I found the abnormal phenomenon ocurred to the "base" tag in jsp. then  after I remove the tag ,it jumps to the specified jsp.Finally stil thank you for your attention to my question.